# Mac OS X 10.6 - How to copy files with logging?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to generate a log of copied files in OS X 10.6? Is there a Mac application that can copy files with logging?

Thanks

Comment: `cp -v` on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `rsync -v`. It's far more versatile than `cp`.